# Embedded jetty: how to authenticate static contents

Tags: java, jetty

I use embedded jetty 8.1.16 to deploy my application. The app has a directory to store the static contents (javascript and css files). The application is authenticated but the static contents could be accessed by their url without authentication. I set up the form based authentication as follows

```
ServletContextHandler handler = (ServletContextHandler)context; 
handler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DefaultServlet() { /* login page*/}), "/login");
Constraint constraint = new Constraint();
constraint.setName(Constraint.__FORM_AUTH);
constraint.setRoles(new String[]{"user"});
constraint.setAuthenticate(true);

ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = new ConstraintMapping();
constraintMapping.setConstraint(constraint);
constraintMapping.setPathSpec("/test-app");

ConstraintSecurityHandler securityHandler = new ConstraintSecurityHandler();
securityHandler.addConstraintMapping(constraintMapping);

HashLoginService loginService = new HashLoginService();
loginService.setConfig("/realm.properties");

FormAuthenticator authenticator = new FormAuthenticator("/login", "/login", false);
securityHandler.setAuthenticator(authenticator);

handler.setSecurityHandler(securityHandler);
```

The static contents have url as localhost:8080/test-app/js/app.js and localhost:8080/test-app/js/app.css
How can I authenticate these static contents to prevent a direct access from url? Thanks